# Embedding a List of YouTube videos in an iframe

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I am trying to embed a list of YouTube videos into a website. The videos don't belong to a particular playlist as such. Random videos will need to be played one after other.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist) article this is possible with the `playlist` property:

> playlist (supported players: AS3, HTML5)
>       Value is a comma-separated list of video IDs to play. If you specify a value, the first video that plays will be the VIDEO_ID specified in the URL path, and the videos specified in the playlist parameter will play thereafter.

However my code doesn't seem to work. Here's what I've tried

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?playlist=PHi4tFz-F0g,HcKrd3K8_A,9fAZIQ-vpdw"
    frameborder="0" />

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PHi4tFz-F0g?autoplay=1&playlist=PHi4tFz-F0g,HcKrd3K8_A,9fAZIQ-vpdw"
        frameborder="0" />
```

I tried putting the video ids list (`PHi4tFz-F0g,HcKrd3K8_A,9fAZIQ-vpdw`) at the demo page [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo), but it doesn't work.

Comment: It actually works on the demo-page (now) - but that uses the api. In a "hard-coded" iframe it doesn't (and nobody will tell me why - Google Search comes up suspisiously empty... getting paranoid!

Comment: hello @gldraphael have you find any solution for this..?

Comment: @Devi Prasad not really. I did it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out, it was just the documentation being confusing:
you can pass the list of video ids, but it has to be a single comma seperated string, not an array
e.g.

```html
 player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'dwM78wnqYK0',
          playerVars: {
          'playsinline': 1,
                  'controls': 1,
                  'playlist': "PHi4tFz-F0g,HcKrd3K8_A,9fAZIQ-vpdw"
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
```